# Taylor series of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} \log(\Gamma(k+1))$

Tags: power-series, gamma-function

Does a the following Taylor series has a closed form expression 
\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{x^k}{k!} \log(k!).
\end{align}

Note that $\Gamma(k+1)=k!$.

Also, note that this power series converges (see for example [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20ln(k!)*x%5Ek%2Fk!%20,%20k%3D0..infinity)).

Comment: So why not just write $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k(\log k!)/k!$?

Comment: Now it is. Typically expression of $\log(\Gamma(z))$ have integral expression.

Comment: I think you mean 'a closed form expression' since, due to the very existence of a convergent Taylor series, the corresponding function is analytic.

Comment: @rafa11111  Yes, I mean closed-form expression. I will change it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not answer, but it is a little long for a comment.

Let 
$$I(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}\log \Gamma(k+a)$$
Then
$$I'(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}\psi^{(0)}(k+a)$$
And because 
$$\psi^{(0)}(k+a)=H_{k+a-1}-\gamma$$
We can find that
\begin{align}
I'(a)&=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}H_{k+a-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\gamma \frac{x^k}{k!} \\
&=\psi^{(0)}(1)e^x+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}H_{k+a-1}
\end{align}
However, I am not sure how to evaluate the last sum.

Comment: It seems like $I'(a)$ is not very useful for computing $I(1)$ without some other value like $I(0)$.

Comment: It's interesting that $I'(1)=e^x(\ln(x)+\Gamma(0,x))$.

Comment: The exponential generating function for the harmonic numbers may be useful.

Comment: Found it $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{n!}x^n = -e^{x}\left(\text{Ei}(-x)-\ln{|x|}-\gamma \right)$$